# Visual C# : Connect to Google account

Tags: c#, connection, account

I am trying to connect my Google account and get the html code of my blogger home page. I figure out that need a cookies for keep the connection but I don't know how do that.

The post address for username and pass is "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin"

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private bool Authorize(out string authCode)
{
    bool result = false;
    authCode = "";

    string queryString = String.Format("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&Email={0}&Passwd={1}&service=cloudprint&source={2}", UserName, Password, Source);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(queryString);

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    string responseContent = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

    string[] split = responseContent.Split('\n');
    foreach (string s in split)
    {
        string[] nvsplit = s.Split('=');
        if (nvsplit.Length == 2)
        {
            if (nvsplit[0] == "Auth")
            {
                authCode = nvsplit[1];
                result = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

`

Comment: emmm The result is SID LSID and AUTH but how I can just get the "html code" ?

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#RetrievingWithoutQuery

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Code Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/) has some good examples of how to do things.  [Here's an example](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#list_posts) of how to retrieve posts from a blog.  Hope it helps.